# SFML libraries not found

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I am trying to link SFML to a C++ project using CMake. This setup works fine on my Linux machine but when I try to build on my mac, it can't find the library: `ld: library not found for -lsfml-network`. My install for SFML is the exact same (in the way I did it) on both machines.

My CMakeLists.txt linking looks as follows:

`target_link_libraries( Playground ${OpenCV_LIBS} sfml-network sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-system )`

Comment: Can you make it work without `cmake`? Then you can at least rule out influence of that and reduce your question accordingly. This follows the rule of extracting an MCVE, which you should know from the guidelines for good questions.

Comment: Hmm, hadn't tried that. It works through normal linking but not through CMake, why is that?

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` after cmake to see exactly what flags cmake is giving the compiler. That can make it easier to diagnose the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFML has a tutorial on [how to compile using CMake](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake). It provides a `FindSFML.cmake` file, so you can simply use `find_package` and `target_link_libraries`:

```
find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS network window graphics system)
# ...

target_link_libraries(Playground
  ${SFML_LIBRARIES}

# If SFML did it correctly, this shouldn't be needed, but I can't tell from the
# documentation if they did:
  ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES}
)
```

Comment: The `FindSFML.cmake` file has recently been removed (though it can be found in previous versions of the source repo) while the tutorial at this time does not appear to have been updated. It looks like some structural changes to the CMake system were made very recently and I hope to find updated documentation on it soon.

Comment: Update: `FindSFML.cmake` has been replaced by `SFMLConfig.cmake` as explained in [this pull request](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/pull/1335). The usage is similar and slightly simpler.